# Sliding time window for record analysis

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I have a data structure of phone calls.  For this question there are two fields, `CallTime` and `NumberDialled`.

The analysis I want to perform is "Are there more than two calls to the same number in a 10 second window"  The collection is sorted by `CallTime` already and is a `List<Cdr>`.

My solution is

```
List<Cdr> records = GetRecordsSortedByCallTime();
for (int i = 0; i < records.Count; i++)
{
    var baseRecord = records[i];
    for (int j = i; j < records.Count; j++)
    {
        var comparisonRec = records[j];

        if (comparisonRec.CallTime.Subtract(baseRecord.CallTime).TotalSeconds < 20)
        {
            if (comparisonRec.NumberDialled == baseRecord.NumberDialled)
                ReportProblem(baseRecord, comparisonRec);
        }
        else
        {
            // We're more than 20 seconds away from the base record.  Break out of the inner loop
            break; 
        }
    }
}
```

Whis is ugly to say the least.  Is there a better, cleaner and faster way of doing this?

Although I haven't tested this on a large data set, I will be running it on about 100,000 records per hour so there will be a large number of comparisons for each record.

**Update** The data is sorted by time not number as in an earlier version of the question

Comment: If the data is not time sorted already by its nature, I would probably sort it and limit the second loop to the next ones that are within 10 seconds.

Comment: Surely it is not needed to check all those 100.000 records every hour? I would assume you only check the call records for those numbers which are newly called since your last check? Performance should be alright then and not too taxing. I don't know how you could do your sliding window any better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the phone calls are already sorted by call time, you can do the following:

- Initialize a hash table that has a counter for every phone number (the hash table can be first empty and you add elements to it as you go)
- Have two pointers to the linked list of yours, let's call them 'left' and 'right'
- Whenever the timestamp between the 'left' and 'right' call is less than 10 seconds, move 'right' forwards by one, and increment the count of the newly encountered phone number by one
- Whenever the difference is above 10 seconds, move 'left' forwards by one and decrement the count for the phone number from which 'left' pointer left by one
- At any point, if there is a phone number whose counter in the hash table is 3 or more, you have found a phone number that has more than 2 calls within a 10 seconds window

This is a linear-time algorithm and processes all the numbers in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't know you exact structures, so I created my own for this demonstration:

```
class CallRecord
{
    public long NumberDialled { get; set; }
    public DateTime Stamp { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var calls = new List<CallRecord>()
        {
            new CallRecord { NumberDialled=123, Stamp=new DateTime(2011,01,01,10,10,0) },
            new CallRecord { NumberDialled=123, Stamp=new DateTime(2011,01,01,10,10,9) },
            new CallRecord { NumberDialled=123, Stamp=new DateTime(2011,01,01,10,10,18) },
        };

        var dupCalls = calls.Where(x => calls.Any(y => y.NumberDialled == x.NumberDialled && (x.Stamp - y.Stamp).Seconds > 0 && (x.Stamp - y.Stamp).Seconds <= 10)).Select(x => x.NumberDialled).Distinct();

        foreach (var dupCall in dupCalls)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dupCall);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The LINQ expression loops through all records and finds records which are ahead of the current record (`.Seconds > 0`), and within the time limit (`.Seconds <= 10`). This might be a bit of a performance hog due to the `Any` method constantly going over your whole list, but at least the code is cleaner :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommand you to use [Rx Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609) and the [Interval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.interval%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method.

> The Reactive Extensions (Rx) is a library for composing asynchronous and event-based programs using observable sequences and LINQ-style query operators. Using Rx, developers represent asynchronous data streams with Observables, query asynchronous data streams using LINQ operators, and parameterize the concurrency in the asynchronous data streams using Schedulers

The **Interval** method returns an observable sequence that produces a value after each period

Here is quick example :

```
    var callsPer10Seconds = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

    from x in callsPer10Seconds 
           group x by x into g 
           let count = g.Count() 
           orderby count descending 
           select new {Value = g.Key, Count = count}; 

    foreach (var x in q) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Value: " + x.Value + " Count: " + x.Count); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
records.OrderBy(p => p.CallTime)
    .GroupBy(p => p.NumberDialled)
    .Select(p => new { number = p.Key, cdr = p.ToList() })
    .Select(p => new
    {
        number = p.number,
        cdr =
            p.cdr.Select((value, index) => index == 0 ? null : (TimeSpan?)(value.CallTime - p.cdr[index - 1].CallTime))
            .FirstOrDefault(q => q.HasValue && q.Value.TotalSeconds < 10)
    }).Where(p => p.cdr != null);
```

Answer (score 0):

In two steps :

1. Generate an enumeration with the call itself and all calls in the interesting span
2. Filter this list to find consecutive calls

The computation is done in parallel on each record using the AsParallel extension method.

It is also possible to not call the ToArray at the end and let the computation be done while other code could execute on the thread instead of forcing it to wait for the parallel computation to finish.

```
var records = new [] {
    new { CallTime= DateTime.Now, NumberDialled = 1 },
    new { CallTime= DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(1), NumberDialled = 1 }
};
var span = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

// Select for each call itself and all other calls in the next 'span' seconds
var callInfos = records.AsParallel()
    .Select((r, i) =>
        new
        {
            Record = r,
            Following = records.Skip(i+1)
                            .TakeWhile(r2 => r2.CallTime - r.CallTime < span)
        }
    );

// Filter the calls that interest us
var problematic = (from callinfo in callInfos 
                where callinfo.Following.Any(r => callinfo.Record.NumberDialled == r.NumberDialled)
                select callinfo.Record)
                .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If performance is acceptable (which I think it should be, since 100k records is not particularly many), this approach is (I think) nice and clean:

First we group up the records by number:

```
var byNumber = 
    from cdr in calls
    group cdr by cdr.NumberDialled into g
    select new 
             {
                 NumberDialled = g.Key,
                 Calls = g.OrderBy(cdr => cdr.CallTime)
             };
```

What we do now is `Zip` (.NET 4) each calls collection with itself-shifted-by-one, to transform the list of call times into a list of **gaps** between calls. We then look for numbers where there's a gap of at most 10 seconds:

```
var interestingNumbers =
    from g in byNumber
    let callGaps = g.Calls.Zip(g.Calls.Skip(1), 
        (cdr1, cdr2) => cdr2.CallTime - cdr1.CallTime)
    where callGaps.Any(ts => ts.TotalSeconds <= 10)
    select g.NumberDialled;
```

Now `interestingNumbers` is a sequence of the numbers of interest.